# Como hacer una validación a nivel vista dentro de un xhtml para mostrar datos?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Tengo la siguiente lista, a la cual le paso un find y me regresa una lista de registros

```
listNivelesPersona2 = nivelesPersonaService.findNivelesPersonaConsultaHorario(cvePersona);
```

dentro de esa lista hay un campo fechaFin, en algunos casos esa fecha tiene el valor 31/12/3000

Yo pinto ese campo en una tabla, pero cuando ese campo venga con esa fecha yo no debo pintar nada

```html
<p:column headerText="Vigencia">
  <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.fecInicioNivel}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
  </h:outputText> -

  <h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.fecFinNivel} ">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
  </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

tengo el siguiente codigo para la condicion

```
String strFecha = "31/12/3000";
    Date fechaFinNivel;
    String fechaFormateada;

    for (NivelesPersona nivelesPersona : listNivelesPersona2) {
        if (nivelesPersona.getFecFinNivel()!= null) {
            fechaFinNivel = nivelesPersona.getFecFinNivel();

            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            fechaFormateada = sdf1.format(fechaFinNivel);

            if (fechaFormateada.equals(strFecha)) {
                fechaFin = "";
            }
        }

    }
```

comparo la fecha que viene de mi lista con la fecha 31/12/300
y si son iguales que me muestre un atributo vació
pero como hago la condición en mi vista, bueno en la columna que puse que muestro la fecha, para que cuando sea igual a esa fecha, muestre ese atributoy sino es igual, pues mostrar la que ya tengo por default
hay algun tipo de if que pueda usar en la vista?

Asi tengo el nuevo metodo

```
   public boolean fechaValida(Date fechaFinNivel) {
    listNivelesPersona2 = nivelesPersonaService.findNivelesPersonaConsultaHorario(cvePersona);
    fechaFinNivel = listNivelesPersona2.get(0).getFecFinNivel();

    String strFecha = "31/12/3000";
    String fechaFormateada;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    fechaFormateada = sdf1.format(fechaFinNivel);

    return !fechaFormateada.equals(strFecha);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias establecer dichas fechas como `null` en el mismo loop que ya implementaste, para que sea mucho mas facil compararlas en la vista.

Asi podrias usar el atributo rendered para mostrarla de forma condicional:

```
<h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.fecFinNivel} "
    rendered="#{consultaHorario.fecFinNivel ne null}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

Ahi la comparacion es *not-equal* `ne`, puedes ver el resto de operadores en el siguiente [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html)

---

Si no puedes por alguna razon modificar dicho atributo, entonces la comparacion se vuelve mas complicada porque invocarias un metodo de tu bean para realizarla:

```
<h:outputText value="#{consultaHorario.fecFinNivel} "
    rendered="#{bean.fechaValida(consultaHorario.fecFinNivel)}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

Y en tu bean definir el metodo que lo valida:

```
public boolean fechaValida(Date date) {
    String strFecha = "31/12/3000";
    String fechaFormateada = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
    return !strFecha.equals(fechaFormateada);
}
```

Comment: pero si establezco las dos fechas como null, que serian fechaFormateada y  strFecha , entonces como hace la comparación?

Comment: no entiendo a lo que te refieres. Yo te digo que iteres en tu `listNivelesPersona2` y para cada elemento que tenga una `fecFinNivel` igual a `31/12/3000` la establezcas en `null`

Comment: acabo de editar la pregunta en como lo tengo, no se si a eso te refieras, si funciona, pero el detalle esta en que si hago eso, en la bd se cambia autimaticamente, en los registros que tengan esa fecha se cambian a null, entonces por eso no lo deje asi

Comment: @ Klaimmore, ya lo implemente y si funciono, en el sentido de que ya no muestra esa fecha, pero sucede lo mismo con las demas fechas que son diferentes de 3000/12/31, en ese campo tengo otras fechas y tampoco las muestra

Comment: @Root93 Eso es porque en tu implementación, sobreescribes el argumento de la función fechaValida por la fecha del elemento en la posición 0. ¿Porque lo hiciste así?

Comment: por noob, ya lo cambie y funciono, gracias

Comment: hago el mismo procedimiento pero para un <p:calendar> que también no debe de pintar esa fecha, pero en este caso cuando implemento el método, desaparece totalmente la cajita del p:calendar, en lugar de solo la fecha, desaparece todo